# Display a 'string' from 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader'. Access Database to C# Form

Tags: c#, forms, ms-access, computer-science, oledbdatareader

Trying to display a value from Access Database to display onto ListBox on a form. The previous form sends this form a string which is 'prevval'- for reference to the code. Not entirely sure what the issue is? Please Help!!
The QuestionID is technically a number but is it an issue if im making it a string because its being presented on the ListBox?

> Error System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E10): No value given
>   for one or more required parameters

Code:

```
       try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = "SELECT QuestionID FROM tblQuestions WHERE (Topic='" + prevval + "')";
            command.CommandText = query;
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                listQuestions.Items.Add(reader.ToString());
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }
```

Comment: What is the type of `Topic` column and what is the value of `prevval` exactly? And of course, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Also `reader.ToString()` returns it's full class name instead of a data inside of it. You need to use `reader[0]`or as a better `GetXXX` methods of it.

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown?

Comment: prevval can vary from different words, depending on the word, will depend on what QuestionID is obtained and what is next displayed.

Comment: changing listQuestions.Items.Add(reader.ToString()); to listQuestions.Items.Add(reader[0]); Solved my issue, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
listQuestions.Items.Add(reader["QuestionID"].ToString());
```

Comment: That's true but this is not the reason of this exception.

Comment: Correct. I'm assuming that prevval is correctly passed as string and has a value.